# Any tips and tricks to get a better Wi-Fi connection in airports?

Tags: airports, tips-and-tricks, wifi

Many airports offer free Wi-Fi but the strength and stability of the signal depends considerably on where you are. Sometimes you get 3+ Mbps (still too slow IMHO but acceptable given that it's free and the place is too large) but in other cases you  couldn't connect to the network even though you catch the signal, which happens too frequently. Even places where you are able to connect, the speed is mere 0.1 Mbps or so, which must be almost useless except the use of messaging apps.

Is there anything you can still do to get the better signal and/or connect to it successfully to begin with?

I have experienced that in many airports, you barely get a signal in baggage waiting and customs area. But is there any other tips and tricks, or any tendency that makes it more likely to enjoy the Wi-Fi, for example where you should be, etc...?

Comment: IMHO latency and packet loss are more important than throughput.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the physical location, you may simply be exhausting the network's capacity to onboard a new client. This are some technical details that I won't bore you with but the bottom line is:

1. Move to a different location.
2. Some food establishments at airports offer their own wifi - you may have to buy a drink or so, but its a great option if you are desperate to get online.
3. Pay for the premium wifi - every airport I have been to offers this option.
4. Use the wired internet option if offered. This is usually available at the lounge areas, but you'll find it is easier to connect since almost no one is using it. Great if you need to work on a laptop.

If you are technically savvy:

1. Assign the network configuration manually without using DHCP
2. Use public DNS servers, as this can often lead to lag.
3. As a general tip for security reasons, and it also helps with the lag - use a VPN service.

By the way, many people would kill for 3+ Mbps.

Comment: I don't understand the second technically savvy point.  You are recommending public DNS servers, but saying they lead to lag, which we should want to avoid?

Comment: @gerrit I read that as *Use public DNS servers, as using the WiFi's built-in one can often lead to lag*.

Comment: Thanks. But does VPN help with the lag here? For me it sounds waiting for the establish of one more connection layer.

Comment: It does because in addition to securing your network, the VPN uses its own (less crowded) DNS resolvers.